# array_push() doesn't push data into an array

Tags: php

I am trying to use `array_push()`, and for some reasons, nothing got push into my array.

Here is what I did :

```
foreach ($intersect_sku_array as $key ) {
   $inserted_array[] =  $key;
}

// dd($inserted_array); at this point, it works

foreach ($valid_array as $key => $value ) {           
   if ( in_array( strtolower($key) , $intersect_sku_array )){
     array_push($inserted_array, $value['name'] ); 
    }
}


dd($inserted_array);
```

What I have :

```
array (size=18795)
  0 => string 'bs-0003r' (length=8)
  1 => string 'bs-0003r-a488' (length=13)
  2 => string 'bs-0003r-pe' (length=11)
  3 => string 'bs-0004r' (length=8)
  4 => string 'bs-0004r-hrp' (length=12)
  5 => string 'bs-0006r' (length=8)
  6 => string 'bs-0006r-cy5' (length=12)
  7 => string 'bs-0006r-fitc' (length=13)
  8 => string 'bs-0006r-hrp' (length=12)
  9 => string 'bs-0007r' (length=8)
.... more
```

I'm trying to add :

```
$value['name'] = string 'Rabbit Anti-TSHR Polyclonal Antibody' (length=36)
```

Output (the same as what I have ) :

```
array (size=18795)
  0 => string 'bs-0003r' (length=8)
  1 => string 'bs-0003r-a488' (length=13)
  2 => string 'bs-0003r-pe' (length=11)
  3 => string 'bs-0004r' (length=8)
  4 => string 'bs-0004r-hrp' (length=12)
  5 => string 'bs-0006r' (length=8)
  6 => string 'bs-0006r-cy5' (length=12)
  7 => string 'bs-0006r-fitc' (length=13)
  8 => string 'bs-0006r-hrp' (length=12)
  9 => string 'bs-0007r' (length=8)
.... more
```

What I expect to have something like this :

```
'bs-0003R' => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'Rabbit Anti-TSHR Polyclonal Antibody' (length=36)
```

Can someone point out what I did wrong?

Comment: What input do you have, what output do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: You do 2 different things. The code that work there is no "if" so maybe your code never goes through your if condition

Comment: @bub : I think it goes through, why do I say that ? because I set `$x = in_array( strtolower($key) , $intersect_sku_array )` and when I `dd($x)` I got `boolean true`

Comment: @Rizier123 Did I answer you question ?

Answer (score 0):

- Your expected output's **data structure** does *not* match your current output's data structure, i.e. the array structures are different. You expect the SKUs to be keys with sub-fields, but you are actually just putting the SKUs in as values.
- `array_push` isn't the answer here if you want to just add a sub-field ("name") to an existing item in the array... or if you want to do anything with existing keys in any case.
- You're not really clear on what you're trying to accomplish conceptually.

I'll make an attempt to solve your problem despite the discrepancies:

```
<?php

$intersect_sku_array = array( // known SKUs?
    'bs-0003r',
    'bs-0003r-a488',
    'bs-0003r-pe',
    'bs-0004r',
    'bs-0004r-hrp',
    'bs-0006r',
    'bs-0006r-cy5',
    'bs-0006r-fitc',
    'bs-0006r-hrp',
    'bs-0007r'
);

$valid_array = array( // SKU info that is available?
    'bs-0003R' => array(
        'name' => 'Rabbit Anti-TSHR Polyclonal Antibody'
    )
);

var_dump($intersect_sku_array,$valid_array);

$inserted_array = array_flip($intersect_sku_array); // this works a little different than the `foreach` in the OP

var_dump($inserted_array); // see for yourself

foreach ( $valid_array as $key => $value ) {
    $key = strtolower($key); // maintain the lowercase key
    if ( isset($inserted_array[$key]) ) { // this will avoid creating new values below
        $inserted_array[$key] = array('name'=>$value['name']); // apply the name property
    }
}

var_dump($inserted_array);

?>
```

Alternatively, you may want the entire contents of the item within `$valid_array`, in which case you could do something like:

```
<?php
// ...
    if ( isset($inserted_array[$key]) ) {
        $inserted_array[$key] = $value; // copy the whole thing
    }
// ...
?>
```